# Rabbitmq different message types in one queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, queue, amqp

Is there any solution for sharing one queue among different message types?

I know topic exchange, but its use different queue.

Answer (score 8):

RabbitMQ is agnostic to the type/content of messages, so you can easily publish very different types of data to a single queue. It's your application that has to handle the parsing. For this, I'll present two solutions:

**Message headers**

You can use the message headers to add additional information about the type of message.

```
Dictionary<string, object> headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
headers("type", "type1");

IBasicProperties basicProperties = model.CreateBasicProperties();
basicProperties.Headers = headers;
byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
model.BasicPublish(_headersExchange, "", basicProperties, messageBytes);
```

Since it uses the message headers, you can later always route them to different queues using a header exchange, so that's one benefit over the next approach.

To use the header after receiving a message, you can use something like this:

```
deliveryArguments.BasicProperties.Headers[headerKey]
```

**Encoding message type in message body**

You can also define your own message format, or add an additional field describing the type of data. But this implementation is highly dependent on your current message format, so I don't think it would make sense to give an example.

Comment: Another issue is to properly filter in consumer handler target message types (in case above of "type1") only